# NGINX load_module error - How to load modules from an include file?

Tags: nginx

I have defined a settings for nginx server

```
load_module /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf;
include load_modules.include;

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
http { upstream educa {
    server      unix:///tmp/educa.sock;
}


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.educaproject.com educaproject.com;
    access_log   off;
    error_log    /home/anton/Course-system/educa/config/logs/nginx_error.log;
    location / {
        include      /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass   educa;
    }
}}
```

However, using the command, i got error
'sudo nginx
nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf" failed (/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf: file too short) in /home/anton/Course-system/educa/config/nginx.conf:1

Text of load_ 50-mod-http-image-filter.conf file is "module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define all `load_module` directives right in the nginx.conf OR with an include file that will be included and have the `load_module` directives you want. The `load_module` directive is only allowed in the main-configuration context. Make sure all your `load_module` statements are defined there:

```
user  nginx;                                                  
worker_processes  auto;                                       
                                                              
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;                     
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;                                
                                                              

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf;
                                                              
events {                                                      
    worker_connections  1024;                                 
}                                                             
                                                              
                                                              
http {   
....
}
```

ProTip:
I name all special includes not *.conf because that gives me more control on how and where to include them. I can still use something like `include *.conf` later in my `http` block without breaking anything.

Comment: i have added these strings load_module /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf;
include load_modules.include; and got error "load_module" directive is not allowed

Comment: Okay please Update your question with the content of your `nginx.conf` as well as the content of `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf`. That will help to understand the problem a little bit better and I will update my configuration example

Comment: Done, but I figured out that line "load_module" should be the first, but I also get an error "nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf" failed (/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf: file too short) in /home/anton/Course-system/educa/config/nginx.conf:1"

Comment: This will not work. The `load_module` directive needs an module-file not a config file. Whats the content of this file: `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf`?

Comment: The content is "load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;"

Comment: So then you should just load the module like described in my config above.